# Hyperlink over embedded SVG

Tags: html, object, svg

I have a page with an object tag that contains a SVG. Is there an easy method to make it clickable (in order to show a larger version in a popup when clicked)?

Comment: I tried with onclick on the object tag and on the parent tag, but it seems the embedded object eats away the clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put `onclick="doSth()"` inside the `<svg>` tag.